# In Angular 8, how can we skip a page to the 4th page from 2nd page on click of 'Next' button if we have 4 pages?

Tags: html, css, angular

For an Angular application, if we have say, 4 pages and currently we are in the 2nd page and on click of 'Next' button in the 2nd page , I want to reach the 4th page by skipping the 3rd page.

In short, need to omit a page and reach the last page on click of 'Next' button.

Comment: Is it about pagination on table. or any other else

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site